# Clear Browser Cache of Certificates Used for Authentication

Tags: authentication, certificates, web-browser

We are using cert based authentication where the client sends a cert to the server, which is validated for authentication for a web application. This all works well. The problem happens when the user attempts to logs out. The browser seems to hold on to the cert and the user is immediately re-authenticated. We have tried closing the browser and reopening it, but it hasn't helped. We see this behavior on Chrome and Firefox alike.

Is it possible to clear the cert cache?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. If web server requests/requires client certificate, browser will automatically attempt to find and send client certificate for authentication. Certificate-based authentication is not the same as cookie authentication.

Comment: Are the pages being cached? Use [response headers](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers) to tell the browser not to cache pages from the website. Agree with @Crypt32. Additionally you should verify session fixation is not an issue. Is the session being properly terminated on logout and a new session ID issued at login?